# Check how many times query param exists in url, if beginning with certain characters

Tags: javascript, url

I wanted to check how many times, a query param exists in a URL, which begins with `org`.

`For example: www.myurl.com/booking?org[0]=LGW&org[1]=LTN&org[2]=SEN&org[3]=STN`

Sometimes the URL might contain `org` once. Sometimes it maybe 10 times.  Basically, How can I loop through the url.  But it will always be `org[number]=value`

Here's a solution I have tried which works.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
let url1 = new URL(window.location.href);
let searchParams = Array.from(url1.searchParams);
let searchParamsUniqueKeys = [];

for (const p of searchParams) {
    if (p[0].substring(0, 3) == "org") {
        console.log("p", p[0])
    }
}
```

This console.logs:

```
p org[0]
p org[1]
p org[2]
p org[3]
```

But adding `.length` as below, console.logs `6`. Not sure why...

```
let url1 = new URL(window.location.href);
let searchParams = Array.from(url1.searchParams);
let searchParamsUniqueKeys = [];

for (const p of searchParams) {
    if (p[0].substring(0, 3) == "org") {
        console.log("p", p[0].length)
    }
}
```

Comment: Query parameters will be featured in the URL following a `?` character: `www.example.com/booking?org[0]=abc&org[1]=123...` Also, what have you tried so far while trying to solve the problem? What failed in those attempts? What's your relevant "*[mcve]*" code?

Comment: It's not closed.

Comment: As Simone said, it's not closed. Nor, to be clear, have I down-voted the question or voted to close. The reasons for those actions may be that you didn't share code in the original question, you didn't explain how your own attempt(s) had failed or broken, posted a link that had no search query parameters (the `?` character is important in the URL) and insufficient information. For guidance on what we expect of questions here - although your reputation suggests you should know - please see: "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*".

Comment: As for the inconsistency, yeah: we know. It's not the best situation, but new questions are expected to follow the requirements, while historical/old questions are left alone because the rules have changed. Couple that with the obvious problems of human inconsistency and many questions that *should* be closed aren't. While there were reasons to down-vote here, I chose *not* to because I was hoping you'd improve the question (which you did! Thank you for that), so...while non-ideal, it worked this specific time. I *am* sorry if it seemed hostile, that truly wasn't my intent.

Comment: @DavidThomas - No problem at all.  I'll make sure I do this going forwards and I appreciate you coming back to me.  And not hostile at all don't worry, I appreciate you most see a lot of questions like this!  Thank you for your help and time today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a code like that:

```js
let url = new URL('https://www.myurl.com/?booking&org[0]=LGW&org[1]=LTN&org[2]=SEN&org[3]=STN');
console.log([...url.searchParams].map(el => el.includes('org')).length);
```

Reference:

- [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)
- [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: thank you, this is much cleaner than my solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, based on what I posted above.  Pushing the values into an array and then calculating the length.

```
let url1 = new URL(window.location.href);
let searchParams = Array.from(url1.searchParams);
let searchParamsUniqueKeys = [];

for (const p of searchParams) {
    if (p[0].substring(0, 3) == "org") {
        console.log("p", p[0])

        searchParamsUniqueKeys.push(p[0])
    }
}

console.log("result", searchParamsUniqueKeys.length);
```